# Laravel Subdomain Routing 'this site can't be reached' error

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7

I need to develop a project with subdomains in Laravel 7.28. I'll pass subdomain variable and check whether that user belongs to that particular domain. I have installed Xampp on local. I tried these two ways:

1

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.myapp.com')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/', 'CRM/HomeController@index')->name('subdomain-index');
});
```

2

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.localhost'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CRM\HomeController@index')->name('crm.index');

    Route::get('login', 'CRM\LoginController@login')->name('crm.login');
    Route::post('login', 'CRM\LoginController@postLogin')->name('crm.login.post');
    Route::get('register', 'CRM\RegisterController@register')->name('crm.register');
    Route::post('register', 'CRM\RegisterController@postRegister')->name('crm.register.post');
    Route::get('logout', 'CRM\LoginController@logout')->name('crm.logout');

});
```

When I type 'demo.localhost' that brings me the same content of 'localhost'. When 'demo.myapp.com' I get 'This site can't be reached' error.

[image: this site can't be reached]

Inside of CRM/HomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\CRM;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index($subdomain)
    {
        echo '1';
        die();
    }
}
```

Where did I do wrong? I tried the official way and questions from StackOverFlow but I can't see my mistake. Any help?

Comment: by the way in .env 'APP_URL=http://localhost'

Comment: did you handel subdomain in your server ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes, it is on localhost by Xampp now

Comment: localhost is main doman how your dealing with subdomain ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes, I'm trying to build the project on localhost. so, localhost is my domain at the moment

Comment: Do you have `demo.myapp.com` aliased to localhost in your hosts file for your computer? Otherwise, it's going to be trying to find the IP for the actual domain, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @aynber how can i do that? could you help?

Comment: @aynber if i want to add another subdomain should i add it to hosts file?

Comment: Read up on how the hosts file works. It's in a different place for different OSes (Mac and linux, it's in /etc/hosts, I forget where it is for Windows). And yes, any subdomain you create to be used for localhost should be added to hosts

Comment: you can use laragon in windows it create `folderName.test` domain for you so test subdomain you can create a folder name with subdomain `subdomain.foldername.test` it will work  https://laragon.org/ i use like this to test subdomain